# Improved clojurescipt repl functionality for descjop project

Tags: electron, clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop

I'm building a project based on descjop and reagent, created using the command:

```
lein new descjop <myproj> +reagent
```

The repl started by lein figwheel works ok but has very basic functionality. There is no command history, and no cursor control. Ideally I would like the full cider/nrepl/clj-refactor functionality but just some basic history and command editing would do.

Is there any easy way to improve the current repl? I have tried exploring the generated code, but I can't see how the decjop template is setting up the clojurescript repl. Any clues to how this works would be helpful.

Alternatively is there any way I can set up an alternative clojurescript repl to connect with my running electron app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a Unix type machine then you can install `rlwrap`. Then instead of starting the REPL from the command line like so:

```
lein figwheel
```

Start it like this:

```
rlwrap lein figwheel
```

Then you will get history (using up and down arrows) and basic editing.

Comment: I'm on OSX which doesn't come with rlwrap, but easily fixed that with port install rlwrap. Thanks, this gets things working for me.